# How to hire multiple groups in Grand Prix Story

Tags: grand-prix-story

In [Grand Prix Story](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.kairosoft.android.paddock_en&rdid=net.kairosoft.android.paddock_en&rdot=1&pli=1), I've just won the first Grand Prix. When I entered the championship, the game told me about how having multiple groups can really help (also every time you research/upgrade something, you have to select the group that should perform the work).

But when I attempt to hire new drivers/mechanics, the secretary complains about there being no room and that I had to fire people.

How do I create a second group of driver+mechanics in *Grand Prix Story*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out:

About three weeks after winning the first Grand Prix, a bear (yes, a bear) will come by your garage and offer to renovate it, not just expanding your "mechanic-capacity" to 4 but also giving you a second group.

Comment: the magical mystery bear of garage renovation. i'll need to keep an eye out for that in real life.